# Excel: Highlight cell if greater than cell in next row

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I've looked at all the tutorials on how to do this but just cant get it to work, I want to highlight the cell in column A if greater than or equal to the adjacent cell in column B, and repeat this all the way down, the formula I have is:

```
=A2>=B2       Applies to: =$A:$A
```

It seems to highlight the cells randomly and incorrectly.

Comment: Change that to `=A1>=B1`. Or maybe `=AND(A1<>"",A1>=B1)`.

Comment: Changing it to =A1>=B1 has worked, thanks.